# Why synchronization using async\await does not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux

I work with react and redux. Want to synchronize some methods(redux actions). As I know it can be done by Promises, or using async\awit. I'm trying to use second variant:

```
const createListIfNotExists = async () => {
    if (list.items.length === 0) {
      dispatch(createList())
    }
  }

  const addItemToList = async (itemId) => {
    await createListIfNotExists();
    dispatch(addItemToList(currentList, itemId));
  };
```

So, I need first to create list and only after it completes I need to go next and to execute `addItemToList`. Unfortunately this does not work - `addItemToList()` fires first and does not wait for `await createReceiptIfNotExists()` to complete.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: because you don't return a promise in `createListIfNotExists` so it resolves "immediately" - does `dispatch` even return a Promise? if so, you should return that (or await it) - and why is `createListIfNotExists` tagged as `async` if you never use `await` in it? makes no sense to do that

Comment: A side note, apart from what @Bravo already mentioned: `dispatch()` expects a Redux action as argument; is your `createList()` function returning a properly formatted action (`{ type: string, payload: any }`)?

Comment: Also, `addItemToList` is the name of the function, but you're also passing a call to that to your dispatch() inside. That's recursion basically. If you imported `addItemToList` from your redux code, your `const addItemToList` is now shadowing it.

Comment: @Bravo will try to return

Comment: @secan yes this is redux action which returns correct dispatch

Comment: dispatch does not return a promise.
If you need to chain logic you should put that logic inside of redux middleware. However your code that creates the list if it doesn't exist can just be inside the reducer

Comment: @Bravo works. could you add your comment to answer section?I will  mark it as answer

Comment: no idea what I said that worked

Comment: @Bravo after returning  in createListIfNotExists it works